# Page showing scroll bar, why I don't know

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

My page is showing a scroll bar on the bottom. I'm using bootstrap 3.0. but I really don't know why the page is showing the scroll bar.

This is the link [Hkonnect](http://guestoutlook.com/demo/). Kindly give me suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: You're not making right use of the `row` class, `.row` elements should be wrapped inside a `.container` otherwise they'll overflow outside the window because of their negative margin

Comment: ok thnx sir, i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is adding this to your CSS:

```
.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

You can add a file to the end of your `<head>` section to cancel it out.  Put this in the CSS file:

```
.row {
    margin-left: 0!important;
    margin-right: 0!important;
}
```

and include like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="/path/to/file.css">
...
</head>
...
```

or put it inline like this:

```
<head>
...
<style>
    .row {
        margin-left: 0!important;
        margin-right: 0!important;
    }
</style>
...
</head>
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Is this does not create any layout issue ?

Comment: as far as I can tell with that page specifically, no.  But you need to check on different pages and with different browsers.  I tested with different screen/window sizes to be sure though.  No issues.